# How can I write this in Divergence form

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE

$u_{xx}-(yu_y)_x-y(u_x)_y+yu_y+(y^2+\frac{1}{H^2(x)})u_{yy}$

I need to write this in divergence form.  That is, I need to write it in the form

$\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j})$

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try formal integration by parts.

Comment: You have to check the task - there must be misprints. For the following equation everything is all-right: $$u_{xx} - x u_{xy} - y u_{xy} + 2 y u_y + (y^2 + \frac{1}{H^2(x)}) u_{yy}.$$